# How to store a checkbox as being checked in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

So I have three blades indes, add and edit.
In my database table i have a schema like:
Schema::create('categories', function($table)

```
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->integer('category');
    });
```

In my add blade I have tried something like:

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <script>
                                    init.push(function () {
                                        $('#categories-status').switcher({
                                            theme: 'checkbox',
                                            on_state_content: '<span class="fa fa-check"></span>',
                                            off_state_content: '<span class="fa fa-times"></span>'
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <label for="category">Speciality</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="categories-status" id="categories-status" value="">
                            </div>
```

And in my controller I have a function "postSave" in which I use

```
 $category->status = ($request->input('status') == 'on') ? 1 : 0;
```

to store the status.
Yet I do not get the results I want, it doesn't save as being checked.
In my index blade I display the checkbox in a table like this:

```
<td>{{ ($category->status == 1) ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}</td>
```

Comment: are sure that comparing integer to string (because you have a string in the database) is feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `"categories.status"` column is nullable, you could just check to see if it's set or not:

```
<td>{{ ($organization->status) ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using blade template, then do it in Laravel way:

Form::checkbox('name', 'value')

For more details check https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html